# Date Format not working in excel vba

Tags: excel, date-formatting, vba

I'm having some difficulties with my datepicker date. StartDate and EndDate are values from DatePicker and Debug.Print will give me "mm/dd/yyyy". I am trying to change the date format to "dd/mmm/yyyy" so that I will be able to compare it with my data from MS access. But it's not working.

```
Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
    Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date

    StartDate = DTPickStart.Value    ' 6/11/2018
    EndDate = DTPickEnd.Value        ' 6/24/2018

    StartDate = Format(StartDate, "dd/mmm/yyyy")
    EndDate = Format(EndDate, "dd/mmm/yyyy")

    Debug.Print StartDate           ' gave me 6/11/2018 instead of 11/Jun/2018
    Debug.Print EndDate
End Sub
```

Any advice on what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a known issue in Excel. Generally, it relates to regional settings of your system. By default, Excel picks the date from there. Check your regional settings, date format there would be mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: @jainashish, my regional settings for short date is indeed M/d/yyyy but it won't work for me to change my regional settings because the file has to be shared across to multiple users. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried Application.International(xlDateOrder) to fetch the end user date format and then manipulating the date accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb177675(v=office.12)) Application.International(Index) method returns information about the current country/region and international settings.

When you apply index as xlDateOrder

```
0 = month-day-year
1 = day-month-year
2 = year-month-day
```

Hence, we will be using this property to override the system behavior. This is especially useful when the Excel-VBA project is used across geographies with various individual regional settings.

Below, I am re-writing your code with a minor tweak. Format function returns the string but you are assigning it to a date which is causing this issue.

```
Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
    Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date
    Dim strStartDate as String, strEndDate as String

    StartDate = DTPickStart.Value    ' 6/11/2018
    EndDate = DTPickEnd.Value        ' 6/24/2018

    strStartDate = Format(StartDate, "dd/mmm/yyyy")
    strEndDate = Format(EndDate, "dd/mmm/yyyy")

    Debug.Print StartDate           ' It will give 11/Jun/2018
    Debug.Print EndDate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Format probably returns the date in the format you want, but it is then transformed into a date-value which is then printed in the default format for your system. To get them stored in the format you want, you could try something like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
    Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String

    StartDate = #6/11/2018#
    EndDate = #6/24/2018#

    'StartDate = Format(StartDate, "dd/mmm/yyyy")
    'EndDate = Format(EndDate, "dd/mmm/yyyy")

    s1 = Format(StartDate, "dd/mmm/yyyy")
    s2 = Format(EndDate, "dd/mmm/yyyy")

    Debug.Print StartDate & " - " & s1          ' gave me 6/11/2018 instead of 11/Jun/2018
    Debug.Print EndDate & " - " & s2
End Sub
```

Alternately if you want them in a cell as dates, you could set the `NumberFormat`  of the range you write them to, to be in your wanted format:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1") = StartDate
Sheet1.Range("A2") = EndDate
Sheet1.Range("A1:A2").NumberFormat = "dd.mmm.yyyy"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to format the date in VBA you have 2 options:

1. Change the regional settings;
2. Write to Excel, format there and bring the `.Text`:

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim StartDate As Date

    StartDate = #6/11/2018#
    Cells(1, 1) = StartDate
    Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "DD/MMM/YYYY"
    Debug.Print Cells(1, 1).Text '11.Jun.2018

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I managed to figure it out, but I'm giving my vote to jainashish as it's closer to how I could use the result to query my access db.